# How to put text in scroll bar?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

so here is code for scrollbar:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
mainloop()
```

i would like to put a paragraph of text inside the scrollbar so the user can scroll down and read the text. how would i do so?

and is there a way to alter the size of the scroll bar to make it larger?

Comment: Where is "there"? Beside the listbox? Below the listbox? Inside the listbox? LIterally inside the thin scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you want to do, but if you want to display a scrollable readonly text, you can use the `Text` widget instead of a `Listbox` (your question does not tell what you want to do with the `Listbox`). The `Scrollbar` is attached to the `Text` widget the same way than with a `Listbox`:

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("200x50")
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text = tk.Text(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.insert("1.0", "Very\n\nlong\n\ntext\n\nto\n\nscroll")
text.pack()
# make text widget readonly
text.configure(state="disabled", highlightthickness=0)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
master.mainloop()
```